# How to change controls set

Tags: unity-control-center

In previous versions of Ubuntu I was able to change the look of controls, i.e. scrollbars, buttons, radios and checks, input lines etc. I do not remember the name of the settings entry but it was somewhere in the control center. Currently control center app is `unity-control-center` but there is no option to do what I want. Is this available some how to change controls, how to do that, where I can download more themes? And no, I am not talking about window decorations and colors.

Comment: Do you know Unity Tweak Tool?

Comment: do you have example of what you did in previous versions ? maybe we could find something similar in latest, but we at least need to know what you're talking about

Comment: @Serg `sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool` and five minutes clicking inside helped, thanks.